# How to add modified, deleted, untracked to a Git repository in GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I thought somehow update=True will add all modified, deleted and untracked files to the index. I am not sure what the way is. Can someone help me here?

```
repo = Repo(working_repository_url)
repo.git.add(update=True)
repo.index.commit(my_msg)
```

I mean. I can certainly get the :

```
untracked_items = repo.untracked_files
```

and this is only for the untracked files. I want to add untracked files, deleted, modified files to the index and then do a commit to all.

More likely I am looking something that is equivalent to `git add --all`

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
repo.git.add(all=True)
```

It's one-to-one correspondence for `git add --all`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use repo.**index**.add(), only repo.**git**.add()

```
repo.git.add('-A')
```

Comment: What does the `-A` flag do?

Comment: Doesn't phd's top-rated answer from over three years ago already say this? Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score -1):

To keep using repo.index:

```py
repo.index.add('**')
```

Comment: This will ignore `.gitignore`